# Does the Gitolite @all group include the gitolite-admin repo?

Tags: gitolite

In my googling, I've only came across statements that state that @all "includes all users and repos"

I'd like to use @all to provide daemon access, that is

```
repo @all
   R = daemon
```

But I'm concerned that would provide read access to the gitolite-admin repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will allow access to *all* repos.

However, you can prevent this, [as documented](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#deny-rules):

```
@secret = gitolite-admin secret-repo/..*
repo @secret
    -   =   daemon
    option deny-rules = 1

repo @all
    R   =   daemon
```

Note that the order matters in this case.